# Selenium python a tag in table

Tags: python, selenium

I'm learniing in python selenium.
I want to make some parsing program.

I can't read the a tag in table

## summary

I want to parsing in a tag

I try to driver.find_element_by_xpath('').click() and driver.find_element_by_css_selector('table[class="board-box"]').click()

## summay

but it can't play...

I don't know where are wrong..

Please help me

There is html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<form name='ArticleList'>
    <table class="board-box">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td class='board-list'>
                    <span>
                        <span class='aaa'>
                            <a class="m-tcol-c" onmouseover="" onclick="return dynamicParamLink('/ArticleRead.nhn?clubid=28279768&page=1&boardtype=L&articleid=91&referrerAllArticles=true', event);" href="/ArticleRead.nhn?clubid=28279768&page=1&boardtype=L&articleid=91&referrerAllArticles=true">API Store</a>
                        </span>
                    </span>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td class='board-list'>
                    <span>
                        <span class='aaa'>
                            <a class="m-tcol-c" onmouseover="" onclick="return dynamicParamLink('/ArticleRead.nhn?clubid=28279768&page=1&boardtype=L&articleid=90&referrerAllArticles=true', event);" href="/ArticleRead.nhn?clubid=28279768&page=1&boardtype=L&articleid=90&referrerAllArticles=true">WikiDocs - Online books platform</a>
                        </span>
                    </span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

`anchor_tag_elements = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')`
should return list of all elements with `a` tag. 
If you want to click one (e.g. first) from list you can call it by index:

```
anchor_tag_elements[0].click()
```

Comment: i try to this code. but it can't

TypeError: 'WebElement' object does not support indexing

Comment: I'm sorry , there is a iframe.
<iframe name="cafe_main" id="cafe_main" src="http://cafe.naver.com/MyCafeIntro.nhn?clubid=28279768" width="773" height="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" allowtransparency="true" style="height: 947px; width: 773px;"></iframe>

Comment: did you tried `find_elements_by_tag_name()` (elementS) or `find_element_by_tag_name()` (element)?

Comment: So, Sorry.. I used find_element_by_tag_name... but now I changed. find_elements_by_tag_name..

I want to make a dashboard parsing tool.

my python summary code is 
#go to dashboard
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='menuLink0']").click()
# find iframe
board_iframe = driver.find_element_by_id('cafe_main')
driver.switch_to_frame(board_iframe)


anchor_element = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')

print anchor_element

but I want to click and parsing next a tag. but it can't.
I try to anchor_element[2].click.. but it can't

Comment: In `Python` indexation starts from [0] element. So, if you want to click first element, you should click `anchor_element[0]`, second-`anchor_element[1]`... That's why you can't use `anchor_element[2]`- there is no third `a` element in provided `html` code

Answer (score 0):

To get all the `<a>` tags in the table you can use - all the `<a>` tags have attribute class "m-tcol-c" (in your html).

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("m-tcol-c")
```

To get the text of the first `<a>` you can use

```
a_text = elements[0].text
```

And to get the href

```
a_href = elements[0].get_attribute("href")
```